Can't get an url but it works when opened in a browser
I have this benthos pipeline :
input:
  http_server:
    address: ""
    path: /post
    ws_path: /post/ws
    allowed_verbs:
      - POST
    timeout: 120s
    rate_limit: ""

pipeline:
  processors:

    # Parse POST input query to get bounding box from body, ie {"tile": a line from all.json}
    - bloblang: |
        root.bbox.x_min = this.tile.split("&").index(0).split("=").index(1)
        root.bbox.x_max = this.tile.split("&").index(1).split("=").index(1)
        root.bbox.y_min = this.tile.split("&").index(2).split("=").index(1)
        root.bbox.y_max = this.tile.split("&").index(3).split("=").index(1)

    - bloblang: |
        root.url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node['amenity'](" + 
          this.bbox.y_min + "," + 
          this.bbox.x_min + "," + 
          this.bbox.y_max + "," + 
          this.bbox.x_max + ");" +
          "way['amenity'](" + 
          this.bbox.y_min + "," + 
          this.bbox.x_min + "," + 
          this.bbox.y_max + "," + 
          this.bbox.x_max + ");" +
          "relation['amenity'](" + 
          this.bbox.y_min + "," + 
          this.bbox.x_min + "," + 
          this.bbox.y_max + "," + 
          this.bbox.x_max + "););out 10 center;"

    # DEBUGGING
    - log: 
        level: info
        message: URL test 
        fields_mapping:
          root.url = this.url

    # Make a request to the Overpass API to fetch data
    - http: 
        url: "${!this.url}"
        verb: GET
        timeout: 60s

    # Parse the JSON response and extract relevant fields (array of elements)
    - bloblang: |
        root.batch = this.response.elements.map_each(e -> if e.tags.amenity != null && e.lat != null && e.lon != null {
          {
            "amenity": e.tags.amenity,
            "lat": e.lat,
            "lon": e.lon
          }
        }).filter(e -> e != null)

output:
  cypher:
    uri: "neo4j://localhost:7687"
    cypher: | 
      UNWIND $batch AS row
      MERGE (p:POI {amenity: row.amenity, lat: row.lat, lon: row.lon})
    # Treat array's rows as batches
    args_mapping: | 
      root.batch = this.batch 
    basic_auth:
      enabled: true
      username: "neo4j"
      password: "neotest"
    batching:
      count: 100
    max_in_flight: 64

The url is formatted correctly (the log output this and it works if you copy paste it into a browser) :
INFO URL test                                      @service=redpanda-connect label="" path=root.pipeline.processors.2 url="https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node['amenity'](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);way['amenity'](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);relation['amenity'](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095););out 10 center;"

But I have this error :
ERRO HTTP request to '${!this.url}' failed: https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node['amenity'](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);way['amenity'](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);relation['amenity'](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095););out 10 center;: HTTP request returned unexpected response code (400): 400 Bad Request, Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head><body><h1>Bad Request</h1><p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br /></p><hr><address>Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) Server at overpass-api.de Port 443</address></body></html>

Do you have any idea of where it could come from?
I also tried to do a root.url = root.url.escape_url_query() after my root.url = ... but it doesn't work too since my URL looks like this after escaping :
https%3A%2F%2Foverpass-api.de%2Fapi%2Finterpreter%3Fdata%3D%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3B%28node%5B%27amenity%27%5D%2849.90146355262061%2C5.875795590895844%2C49.905976047309935%2C5.882782232769095%29%3Bway%5B%27amenity%27%5D%2849.90146355262061%2C5.875795590895844%2C49.905976047309935%2C5.882782232769095%29%3Brelation%5B%27amenity%27%5D%2849.90146355262061%2C5.875795590895844%2C49.905976047309935%2C5.882782232769095%29%3B%29%3Bout+10+center%3B

PS : for testing, an input is a request like this :
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:4195/post -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"tile": "x_min=5.875795590895844&x_max=5.882782232769095&y_min=49.90146355262061&y_max=49.905976047309935"}'

EDIT :
pipeline:
 processors:

# Parse POST input query to get bounding box from body, ie {"tile": a line from all.json}
- bloblang: |
    root.bbox.x_min = this.tile.split("&").index(0).split("=").index(1)
    root.bbox.x_max = this.tile.split("&").index(1).split("=").index(1)
    root.bbox.y_min = this.tile.split("&").index(2).split("=").index(1)
    root.bbox.y_max = this.tile.split("&").index(3).split("=").index(1)

- bloblang: |
    root.url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);way[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);relation[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095););out%2010%20center;"

# Mapping to clear request body
- mapping: |
    meta = deleted()
    meta url = root.url

# Make a request to the Overpass API to fetch data
- http: 
    url: ${! metadata("url") }
    verb: GET
    timeout: 60s

# Parse the JSON response and extract relevant fields (array of elements)
- bloblang: |
    root.batch = this.response.elements.map_each(e -> if e.tags.amenity != null && e.lat != null && e.lon != null {
      {
        "amenity": e.tags.amenity,
        "lat": e.lat,
        "lon": e.lon
      }
    }).filter(e -> e != null)


The issue is that some characters in the URL query need to be escaped using percent encoding. In the URL from your example, you'll have to escape single quotes and spaces like so:
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);way[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);relation[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095););out%2010%20center;

Update: Here is a working config:
input:
  generate:
    count: 1
    mapping: |
      meta url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);way[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);relation[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095););out%2010%20center;"
  processors:
    - http:
        url: ${! metadata("url") }
        verb: GET


thank you a lot for your answer! With this solution I get an EOF error instead, I edited my post to show the complete error message with the new URL.

I think you're still having some issues with the way you're crafting that URL. See the sample config I shared. You can't do root.url = root.url.escape_url_query() since that escapes the whole URL. You should only escape individual segments when crafting the URL components.

I don't think it's because of the URL itself now... because I tried to directly put the URL (i copy pasted the one from your working config) into the http processor and I get the same error. I edited my first message, the only difference I can see is that you use metadata...

That should work. Just make sure the message body is empty before the http processor. That's why I use metadata. Basically, you can do something like a mapping with these 2 lines in it: root = "" and meta url = <set the URL here>. If you run the config I shared, does it work?

Your config work. I tried to implement something (I edited my edit) using metadata after checking the documentation but I get this error : ERRO HTTP request to '${! metadata("url") }' failed: null: Get "null": unsupported protocol scheme ""  @service=redpanda-connect label="" path=root.pipeline.processors.3. I'm not sure on how the root = "" you talk about should be implemented? Thank you again for your help.

First you should replace the bloblang processor with mapping since the latter is deprecated. Then, instead of meta = deleted() you should have meta url = this.url followed by root = "" on the next line to clear the message body. Hope that helps.

Thank you a lot for your help! The URL part works perfectly fine now :) I put my current code in an answer in case anyone else wants to do something similar. I would have last one question: when I do a simple stdout or text file as an output it works pretty quickly. But when the output is my Neo4J database, I get a request time out after I do my input curl, do you have any idea to solve this? I guess it involves playing with timeout/batches parameters but I find it weird that the result is quick with a stdout but my database can't receive data at all...

Glad that worked. Not sure about Neo4J and I feel that should be a different question. You may wish to join the Redpanda Community Slack for that stuff, since I haven't looked at Neo4J at all and I think other people there might know how to help.

Sure, thank you a lot again for your help and your time, i'll look into that!

The current working code to communicate with the OverpassAPI using different bounding box. The goal of the code is to fetch all point of interests from OpenStreetMap by giving a tile as input. An input example is :
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:4195/post -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"tile": "x_min=5.875795590895844&x_max=5.882782232769095&y_min=49.90146355262061&y_max=49.905976047309935"}'

# Listen for a POST HTTP request
input:
  http_server:
    address: ""
    path: /post
    ws_path: /post/ws
    allowed_verbs:
      - POST
    timeout: 120s
    rate_limit: ""

# Bloblang processor will be deprecated: https://docs.redpanda.com/redpanda-connect/components/processors/bloblang/
pipeline:
  processors:

    # Parse POST input query to get bounding box from body, ie the tile
    - mapping: |
        root.bbox.x_min = this.tile.split("&").index(0).split("=").index(1)
        root.bbox.x_max = this.tile.split("&").index(1).split("=").index(1)
        root.bbox.y_min = this.tile.split("&").index(2).split("=").index(1)
        root.bbox.y_max = this.tile.split("&").index(3).split("=").index(1)

        root.url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);way[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095);relation[%27amenity%27](49.90146355262061,5.875795590895844,49.905976047309935,5.882782232769095););out%2010%20center;"

    # Mapping to clear request body with metadata
    - mapping: |
        meta url = this.url
        root = ""

    # Make a request to the Overpass API to fetch data
    - http: 
        url: ${! metadata("url") }
        verb: GET
        timeout: 60s

    # Parse the JSON response and extract relevant fields (array of elements)
    - mapping: |
        root.batch = this.elements.map_each(e -> if e.tags.amenity != null && e.lat != null && e.lon != null {
          {
            "amenity": e.tags.amenity,
            "lat": e.lat,
            "lon": e.lon
          }
        }).filter(e -> e != null)

# Simply output the POIs dictionary in the console as an output
output:
  stdout: {}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
